# Автономный таймер 60 дней

Tags: javascript, html, css, таймер

Как можно реализовать таймер на 60 дней, который начнет работать с момента создания, не зависимо, видел ли его посетитель?

То есть, чтобы он работал сам по себе, с момента появления на странице. Даже если посетитель зашел с другого устройства, почистил кеш - таймер все равно должен работать и отображать остаток от 60 дней с момента когда он был установлен. Блок с таймером будет генерироваться скриптом (да/нет). Таймер будет установлен на 230 страницах.

Comment: да, на сервере =)

Comment: Расскажите подробнее, пожалуйста

Comment: На сервере идет время, веб страница получает эту информацию, все.

Comment: Можно подробнее.Я только изучаю JS.

Comment: На каком языке программирования написан Ваш бэкэнд? он вообще имеется?

Comment: Stranger in the Q, Пока нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Могу посоветовать узнать время на каком-нибудь публичном сервере времени и считать от него:

```js
let timeout;

fetch('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/GMT+0').then(r => r.json()).then(r => {
  timeout = Date.parse("Jan 1, 2020") - Date.parse(r.datetime);
  requestAnimationFrame(calc);
});

function calc(t){
  requestAnimationFrame(calc);
  time.innerHTML = `До нового года осталось ${(timeout-t)/1000/60/60/24} дней`
}
```

```html
<div id=time></div>
```

Comment: Мне надо отсчет 60 дней.До определенной даты - я и сам могу сделать.

Comment: @Garmi в примере таймер на 86 дней, что мешает посчитать через сколько будет 60 дней?

Comment: в примере таймер до 01.01.2020.У нас не будет такой даты.Ее просто не будет.

Comment: @Garmi не понимаю в чем проблема, прибавьте 60 дней к текущей дате, будет ьаймер на 60 дней..

Comment: Как именно это сделать! Чтобы не надо было изменять дату вручную! Я не могу заставить 230 человек что то делать вручную, когда там всем более 60 лет!

Comment: @Garmi иметь одну копию этого скрипта.., и в ней менять

Comment: Как? Я не понимаю вас.

Comment: @Garmi Все страницы ссылаюься на один и тот же скрипт в интернете или локальной сети

Comment: Там дата до 01.01.2020.Я спрашиваю за 60 дней, именно автономный,без вмешательства пользователя

Comment: @Garmi поставьте другую дату, я не понимаю в чем у Вас проблема

Comment: нет.дату не я изменяю.это делают пользователи ресурса,бэкенд сделать только на половину.

Comment: тогда получайте эту дату(окончания таймера) запросом к серверу, а как она туда попадет - это другая история