# Вывод даты + 60 дней в input value

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как можно реализовать (скриптом) вывод сегодняшней  даты +60 дней.То есть, если сегодня, например, 07.10.2019, то чтобы выводилось 06.12.2019? И как с помощью простого скрипта

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
 $('#id1input').attr('value', 'тут дата'); });
 </script>
```

получившеюся дату вывести у value у input?

Comment: Moment.js может пригодиться https://momentjs.com/

Comment: дополняйте старый вопрос, он ведь про то же самое https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1031674/188366

Comment: Нет, не дубликат.У меня есть 230 пользователей, большинство 60+.Я попросил именно как можно реализовать то, что описано в вопросе.Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего это сделать при помощи библиотеки moment.js (лучше всего установить moment-with-locales.js):

```html
<input type="text" id="id1input">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function(){
  moment.locale('ru');
  let datePlus60days = moment().add(60, 'days').calendar();
  $('#id1input').attr('value', datePlus60days);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Пример можно запихать в сниппет, так будет лучше.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, отредактировал

Comment: А как можно изменить формат даты на дд, мм, гггг?

Comment: Или дд. мм. гггг (то есть чтобы был пробел)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f6xdutaL/ почему то не работает

Comment: поправил сниппет

Comment: Спасибо, работает.А как можно изменить формат даты на дд, мм, гггг или дд. мм. гггг (то есть чтобы был пробел) ?

Comment: @Garmi `let datePlus60days = moment().add(60, 'days').format('DD. MM. YYYY'); ` https://jsfiddle.net/tzdgsLa1/

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Comment: Плставил бы вам плюс,да не могу - репутация меньше 15

Comment: появился вопрос - почему когда я применяю скрипт к другому полю, он не работает?айди я, конечно же, изменяю